# ValidationError while using ModelForm Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am very new to Django. I am working on a small project in which I am using `ModelForm`.
For the date field, I want to do custom validation i.e. whenever a user enters a date before today's date it should display an error message near the date field. I have written code as per Django's documentation, but it gives ValidationErrors for the raise statement in model form. like below:

```
ValidationError at /add_task/
[u"Please enter valid date. Either today's date or after that."]
```

Please help me how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

***models.py***

```py
from django.db import models

class MyTask(models.Model):
    summary=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    due_date=models.DateField(null=True)
    completed_status=models.BooleanField()
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.summary
```

***forms.py***

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from assignment.models import MyTask

import datetime

class AddTaskForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=MyTask
        fields=('summary','description','due_date')
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 10}),
            'due_date':SelectDateWidget(),
        }
        
    def get_due_date(self):
        diff=self.cleaned_data['due_date']-datetime.date.today()
        if diff.days<0:
            raise ValidationError("Please enter valid date. Either today's date or after that.")
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['due_date']    
    
    def get_summary(self):
            return self.cleaned_data['summary']


    def get_description(self):
            return self.cleaned_data['description']
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your validation method needs to be called `clean_due_date`. In Django < 3 it should raise `forms.ValidationError`, but in Django 3 it should use `core.exceptions.ValidationError`.

I have no idea what the `get_summary` and `get_description` methods are for, they aren't called and don't do anything useful.

See the Django 3 docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and the Django 2 docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: Hi Daniel, get_summary and get_description methods just return cleaned data to the view and do nothing.Thanks, now it works.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman "it should raise forms.ValidationError, not core.exceptions.ValidationError" You can find in `django/forms/__init__.py` that `ValidationError` is from `core.exceptions` it's just reimported `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`